# Quelle est la signification de « tabitou » ?

Tags: sens, sms-lingo

Sur un site, j'ai trouvé :

> tabitou?

Quelle est la signification de ce mot ?

C'est peut-être l’abréviation d'une phrase ?
J'aimerais bien savoir s'il y a une source pour apprendre ce genre d’abréviation ?

Comment: T'habites où ?, Où habites-tu ? Où est-ce que tu habites ?

Comment: It will probably not be helpful for future visitors.

Comment: I think you should reformulate your question.  It has severe grammar and formatting errors.  I think that if it was asked in a better way, then it may become useful for future visitors.

Comment: auriez-vous la gentilles de ma question corriger? Patrick Sebastien

Comment: Bien sûr.  Je ne suis pas sûr si on accepterait la révision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C'est une phrase écrite sous forme abrégée — du « SMS spique » (*SMS speak*), comme on dit parfois en français. Elle a la même prononciation que la vraie phrase : « T'habites où ? » (c.à.d. « Où habites-tu ? » en français écrit), mais est plus facile à taper.

Il n'y a pas de règle pour former ces phrases, juste la phonétique et le hasard de l'évolution de la langue.